# Image flickers before changing in angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a page to display Customer Info where I show female pic if Gender of Customer is Female or a Gents pic is gender is Male.
Code for HTML:

```
<span class="d-none d-lg-block">
            <div *ngIf="male; else female">
              <img class="circular-image" src="../../../assets/images/male_profile_pic.jpeg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <ng-template #female>
              <img class="circular-image" src="../../../assets/images/female_profile_pic.jpeg" alt="" />
            </ng-template>
          </span>
```

Typescript Code:

```
this.gender = this.sampleData.individualCustomer.gender;
  if (this.gender === 'Male') {
    this.male = true;
  } else {
    this.male = false;
  }
```

However if I load a Male Customer profile for a second I see Female profile pic before it changes to Male profile pic.
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a flag, say `isCustomerLoaded` initialized with `false` set it to `true` once customer profile is loaded.

Use this falg in the template as:

```
<span *ngIf="isCustomerLoaded" class="d-none d-lg-block">
        <div *ngIf="male; else female">
          <img class="circular-image" src="../../../assets/images/male_profile_pic.jpeg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <ng-template #female>
          <img class="circular-image" src="../../../assets/images/female_profile_pic.jpeg" alt="" />
        </ng-template>
</span>
```